# Amazon MWS API: Retrieve Only Orders That Haven't Been Acknowledged?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

The Amazon MWS Reports API has an `Acknowledged` parameter available for returning all outstanding orders that have not been previously acknowledged by the merchant.

So far I haven't been able to find an equivalent parameter that I can use with the MWS Orders API, so I have to work my way through the past 30 days worth of orders using the `ListOrdersByNextToken` call(s), which come with a fairly severe (and apparently incorrectly documented) call threshold and refresh limit. I'm really hoping I've missed something in the documentation and/or the schemas about acknowledged vs. unacknowledged orders with the Orders API.  If this is the case I'd certainly appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Right now I'm leaning towards trying the `LastUpdatedAfter`parameter instead of the `CreatedAfter` parameter, but I'm absolutely certain the former will always retrieve **all** new and unshipped orders from the Amazon Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to acknowledge individual orders by sending Amazon a `_POST_ORDER_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_DATA_` XML feed or a `_POST_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_DATA_` tab delimited feed however, there's no way (as far as I can tell) to solely pull unacknowledged orders using the Orders API.

You can schedule order reports using the Reports API and then pull unacknowledged order reports as you would with other kinds of reports. I think this is probably the closest feature to what you are looking for.